# Run number of transactions per minute in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a test plan like following
       Thread Group
          - Http Request 1
          - Http Request 2
          - Http Request 3
Does anyone know how can I achieve  100 req/min for Http Request 1,40 req/min for Http Request 2 and 10 req/min for Http Request 3
I tried throughput controller but that is only running for 1 min but I need to run all those request each min for 30 mins

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to achieve this is:

- Create Separate Thread Groups for each HTTP Request
- Change your Thread group properties as per your Requirement, 
  Like for Http Request 1 - `Number of Threads` = `100`, Duration - `60` seconds

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve the desired load. The most easy and "safe" solution would be to split the HTTP request in their own Thread-group if possible.

Then add a Constant Throughput Timer in each thread group and configure this to the desired Request per minute. Have a look a the documentation about this module [Jmeter User's Manual](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer), there are multiple setting for this controller to achieve the desired load.